# Generate QR code in Android that handles Intent

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a feature that enables me to scan a `QR-code` and open relevant activity.
NOw I have Recycleview and a random number of items, so I handle onclick of items and open Details Activity with the code -

```
    public void onOrderItemClick(View itemView) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(ORDER_DATA_KEY, order);
    OrderDetailsActivity.launch(itemView.getContext(), bundle);
}
```

Now it is pretty simple to get context from Onclick of item -
As I need the context and BUndle to start the activity

```
    public static void launch(Context context, Bundle orderData) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OrderDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(orderData);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

How Can I generate Relevant QR so that I can directly go to the Corresponding Activity without even clicking the item in the Recycleview?
Any help is very much appreciated .

Comment: I will be obliged dear down-voter, if u make it clear what problem did you find? I just wanted a path/ approach

Comment: Please correct me, You are trying to implement a feature, that when a specific QR Code is scanned, you need to launch specific activities. Right? Also, these QR Codes are printed on a paper

Comment: With this feature, you want to ease user to launch the activity by simply scanning a QR Code, after which, the app will perform activities based on the scanned input. Correct?

Comment: yes, as there can be multiple items in recycler view, so that the user dosent have to scroll through, A qr can  be generated for each item and on scanning it will open the activity with the data of the particular itemview

Comment: @AtishAgrawal And the problem is item views are dynamic and the next activity is fixed but with dynamic random data based on item click on recyclerview

Comment: @Achy97 I am confused by the use case you describe. From a recycleview/list of items are you scanning a QR code or generating a QR code. Is the creator of QR code (customer?) the same app as the QR reader (order taker?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this logic and modify it according to your needs.

**Steps:**

1. Generate QR Codes for each item, initially. A QR Code stores a set of data in image format. So, you can design your own data in a specific pattern like

   **Initial (Sample Original Data)**

   - App-Name-Item-Id-1
   - App-Name-Item-Id-2
   - App-Name-Item-Id-3
   - App-Name-Item-Id-4

   (1,2,3,4 are unique item IDs)

   If you want, you encrypt this data, so that no other QR Code scanner can read the confidential information. You can use any encryption algorithm

   **Encrypted (Random Example)**

   - a3GErWv9exn0dOexUBV07GNM1IS5W5Rj
   - CkOdE2ZQlakJzfg9nhNxBqqa917Cdz7K
   - 78d2Z55QTCpciHr3rFMmtRN3E0HRdHgx
   - RZnZF4wb3WPGuI0C3FjeXf8hCFyDZbiE
2. Create a simple activity which has a single button Scan QR. You can use any open-source library to scan the data in a QR.
3. When a QR is scanned, you will get this kind of the encrypted data, obviously because you embedded it in the QR Itself.
4. Validate the QR
5. Decrypt the data using the same encryption algorithm and verify using any common logical means, as it should be in a pattern (App-Name-Item-Id-[0-9])
6. Once validated, you can easily get the last numerical part from this. Once you have it, you can fetch the data (order object) associated with this unique ID as you must be doing in the ItemClickListener or while creating the adapter
7. Finally, launch the activity as you are doing now

With this, I think you will be able to do it flawlessly.